# How to load ClientCredentialsResourceDetails required parameters from property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to load the required parameters like accessURI,client_id, client_secret from properties file like below. It never loads the properties, I see many sites mention this as example. It is working if I tries to set it explicitly.

In this example
https://dzone.com/articles/build-a-spring-boot-app-with-secure-server-to-serv

```
@Bean()
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="my.oauth2.client")
    protected ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oAuthDetails() {
        return  ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
```

But it never loaded the properties so I need to change to use set methods.I am not able to figure out why it did not load, I believe I cannot mention this in @EnableConfigurationProperties as it does not have the configuration configured.

I tried searching but could not find a matching reason.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the binding of properties to class members works as described in the example.

The properties have to be present either as YAML or properties file:

```
spring:
  security:
   oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        oauth:
          client-id: XXXXXX
          client-secret: YYYYYYY
          scope: openid
          redirect-uri: http://redirect
          access-token-uri: https://token
          client-authentication-method: basic
          authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

Then the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation has to be declared with the correct prefix. In this example it is "spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauth".

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.oauth")
protected ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oAuthDetails() {
    return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
}
```

As stated in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) you normally do not have to set the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation unless you are developing your own auto-configuration.

But if you are working on a non Spring Boot project the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation has to be declared, describing the class where we want to use the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation:

```
@Configuration()
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
public class MyConfig {

}
```

with

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myproperties")
public class MyProperties {

}
```

Alternatively you can also use configuration property scanning which works similarly to the component scanning by declaring the `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan({ "my.app" })
public class MyApplication {
}
```

Hope, this helps. Pero